# Why is there an option to rebuild/reorganize an index when SQL Server does this automatically?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server automatically handles index fragmentation issue when a certain number of rows are inserted/updated.

Then why is there an option to rebuild/reorganize an index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you confusing fragmentation with statistics?

There is no auto handling of fragmentation. Do you have some reference to point to?

There is, however, auto update of statistics. It is a bit crude, which is why we might complement it with scheduled stats update jobs.

Answer (score 1):

The design philosophy of SQL Server is to have most maintenance be automated, but since no automation is perfect, allow manual override for advanced users.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to paraphrase Sheldon Cooper, "Automation is making SQL server more user friendly, I hate that!" The option they have (thankfully) left us to be able to manually control almost every aspect of the SQL server options and behaviour is to me a good thing. Automation is fine, hands on is better.

Comment: * Assuming the DBA knows what they are doing, otherwise automation is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

The updating of statistics is automatic but not well controlled. It is better to have a maintenance plan to manage it.

Index fragmentation fix is not automatic and is related to IO performance.
It is less mandatory in a solution with SSD disks but important with traditional disks.

For both problems my suggestion is to adopt Ola Hallengren's maintenance solution:

https://ola.hallengren.com/